# Inline ARM assembly instructions

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, arm

I wanted to run some ARM assembly instructions in my rust code since I am targeting the raspberry pi. The problem is rust complains about the following:

```
unsafe {
    asm!("ldr r0, =0x3f200000");
}
```

I get `error: Only valid when first operand is register`. But `r0` is an ARM register (?).

Furthermore, instead of using the raw addresses I would like to use constants, but I cannot get that to work either, and after reading the [rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/library-features/asm.html#inputs-and-outputs) on this I still cannot wrap my head around the supposed syntax.

Comment: I don't speak Rust (or aarch64), but looking at the docs, I wonder if you could do something like `let x: u64; unsafe { asm!("ldr {0}, =0x3f200000", out(reg) x); }`?

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work, the accepted answer and this, but I would like to know why this is working, and use it to insert constants in the code instead of the raw address. EDIT: I now understand that this code places the content in address `0x3f200000` in the variable x correct?

Comment: "to insert constants" - Per that link you gave, I'd expect you could do something like `asm!("ldr {0}, ={number}", out(reg) x, number = const 0x3f200000);`.  Obviously I have not tried it.  "this code places the content in address 0x3f200000 in the variable x correct?" - That would be my expectation.  Again, not an aarch64 programmer.  As for what's at that address?  Google gave me [this](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=229343) which has some links.  If you're going to be reading 64bits, make sure that what's stored there is 64bits long or you'll end up reading garbage.

Comment: I tried this just now and it works, I dislike the fact that I cant use that constant anywhere else in the code though, I guess that is just how it works. And yes, I forgot that I needed to read a u64, but helpfully last comment does use a u64 type of the variable that the code is setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r0` is a valid register name in Aarch32 mode.
If you are running Rust in Aarch64 mode, you should use `ldr x0, =0x3f200000` or `ldr w0, =0x3f200000`